# How to hide navbar while navigation menu is extended/opened in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want prevent the navigation bar from dropping down while the navigation menu is opened/extended, I have a piece of javascript that drops the navbar down when user scrolls away from the beginning of the page, navbar will also be hidden when the menu is clicked open, so once the navbar gets hidden when user clicks open the menu, but continues scrolling, the navbar will drop down again, I want to prevent that.
When the close button for the menu is clicked I also want the navbar to not reveal itself **as long** as the user is **at the beginning** of the page. I haven't yet been able to figure out a way around this, I tried using `while` statements in javascript but think I used them incorrectly. Are there any suggestions out there on any way I can reach a solution to this?
Here is the html:

```js
$(".openNav").on("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-50px";
});

$(".closebtn").on("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
});
window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction()
};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-50px";
  }
}
```

```css
#navbar {
  background-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.96);
  position: fixed;
  top: -50px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  transition: top 0.3s;
  z-index: 1;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#navWrap {
  padding: 9px;
}

.openNav {
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #111;
}

.opacity a {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.opacity a:hover {
  color: #818181;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Lorum ipsum</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Lorum ipsum">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="css/nav.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <br>
  <h1>A header</h1>
  <h2 style="margin-top: 130%">another header for scrolling</h2>

  <div id="navbar">
    <a class="openNav">&#9776; Menu</a>
  </div>
  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn">&times;</a>
    <a href='../main/'>Home</a>
    <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        ?>
      <a href="../debugging/Contact.php">Get In Contact</a>
      <a href="../debugging/settings.php">Settings</a>
      <a href="php/logout.php">Logout</a>
      <?php 
        }else{
        ?>
      <a href="../debugging/login.php">Login</a>
      <?php } ?>

      <?php if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){ ?>
      <hr>
      <div class="opacity" style="opacity: 0.20;">
        <a>Get In Contact</a>
        <a>Settings</a>
        <a>Logout</a>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
  </div>

</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/nav.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let isScrolledTop = true
let isSidenavbaropen = false

$(".openNav").on("click", function() {
  showSidenavbar()
  hideNavbar()
  isSidenavbaropen = true
});

$(".closebtn").on("click", function() {
  hideSidenavbar()
  if (!isScrolledTop) {
    showNavbar()
  }
  isSidenavbaropen = false
});

window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction()
};

function scrollFunction() {
  isScrolledTop = !(document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20)
  if (!isScrolledTop && !isSidenavbaropen) {
    showNavbar()
  } else {
    hideNavbar()
  }
}

function hideNavbar() {
  document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-100%";
}

function showNavbar() {
  document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
}

function showSidenavbar() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.left = "0px";
}

function hideSidenavbar() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.left = "-100%";
}
```

```css
#navbar {
  background-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.96);
  position: fixed;
  top: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  transition: top 0.3s;
  z-index: 1;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#navWrap {
  padding: 9px;
}

.openNav {
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #111;
}

.opacity a {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.opacity a:hover {
  color: #818181;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Lorum ipsum</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Lorum ipsum">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="css/nav.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <br>
  <h1>A header</h1>
  <h2 style="margin-top: 130%">another header for scrolling</h2>

  <div id="navbar">
    <a class="openNav">&#9776; Menu</a>
  </div>
  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn">&times;</a>
    <a href='../main/'>Home</a>
    <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        ?>
      <a href="../debugging/Contact.php">Get In Contact</a>
      <a href="../debugging/settings.php">Settings</a>
      <a href="php/logout.php">Logout</a>
      <?php 
        }else{
        ?>
      <a href="../debugging/login.php">Login</a>
      <?php } ?>

      <?php if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){ ?>
      <hr>
      <div class="opacity" style="opacity: 0.20;">
        <a>Get In Contact</a>
        <a>Settings</a>
        <a>Logout</a>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
  </div>

</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/nav.js"></script>

</html>
```

Is this how you wanted it? I hope this helps, you just have to add a bit of if and else

Comment: This was exactly the solution I was looking for, appreciate your assistance. Thankyou!